# Find common words between two strings

Tags: c, string, function, while-loop, char

How do I compare and find common words between two tokenized word strings?

Please help me find a new solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 25

void findSame(char *str1, char *str2) {
    char *word1 = strtok(str1, " ");
    
    while (word1 != NULL) {
        char *word2 = strtok(str2, " ");
        
        while (word2 != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(word1, word2) == 0) {
                printf("%s ", word1);
                break;
            }
            word2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        word1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

int main() {

    char str1[MAX], str2[MAX];
    int i;

    printf("Enter String 1: ");
    gets(str1);
    
    printf("Enter String 2: ");
    gets(str2);
    
    strlwr(str1); //convert strings to lowercase
    strlwr(str2); //convert strings to lowercase
    
    printf("\nOutput:\n");
    findSame(str1, str2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program putput should look like this:

```
Enter String 1: The quick Brown FOX jumped over the LAzy dog
Enter String 2: Hey Quick brown cat and dog
quick brown dog
```

Comment: Unless you want to brute-force it (two loops), or build a container (hash table, search tree or some kind of set), you can do this easily with `qsort`. Just tokenize every word into two arrays, sort each array, and then step through them in tandem (much like the merge operation in merge sort). You can detect duplicates along the way in linear time, so the overall complexity is really governed by the sort which is typically O(N.log(N)). You may get a different output order. If order is important, do another pass where you binary-search the sorted duplicates list using the original order.

Comment: @helloworld123 if a word occurs twice in both strings, should the output have 1 or 2 of that word?

Answer (score 3):

A few issues ...

1. *Never* use `gets`--it is unsafe because it will overrun the buffer without realizing it. Always use `fgets` instead. See: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/5382650)
2. `MAX` is too small to contain the sample input strings. `gets` *will* overrun the buffer causing UB (undefined behavior).
3. In `findSame`, after the *first* loop iteration for `str1`, the *inner* loop for `str2` has already split up the tokens. So, on the second iteration, `word2` will *only* see the *first* word/token of `str2`.
4. We must split [tokenize] the string and save it to a `char *` array. Then, we iterate over these lists of strings.

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <termios.h>

// NOTE/BUG: this is much too small for the input strings
#if 0
#define MAX 25
#else
#define MAX 250
#endif

// splitup -- split up a buffer into tokens
void
splitup(char **list,char *buf)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    // NOTE: this _is_ destructive of the original string

    char *cp = strtok(buf," ");

    while (cp != NULL) {
        if (count >= (MAX - 1))
            exit(2);

        list[count++] = cp;

        cp = strtok(NULL," ");
    }

    list[count] = NULL;
}

void
findSame(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{

    // preserve original string
    char tmp1[MAX];
    strcpy(tmp1,str1);
    // split into tokens
    char *list1[MAX];
    splitup(list1,tmp1);

    // preserve original string
    char tmp2[MAX];
    strcpy(tmp2,str2);
    // split into tokens
    char *list2[MAX];
    splitup(list2,tmp2);

    for (char **word1 = list1;  *word1 != NULL;  ++word1) {
        for (char **word2 = list2;  *word2 != NULL;  ++word2) {
            if (strcmp(*word1, *word2) == 0) {
                printf("%s ", *word1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void
prompt(char *buf,size_t size,const char *str)
{

    printf("%s: ",str);
    fflush(stdout);

    // safe replacement for gets
    char *cp = fgets(buf,size,stdin);
    if (cp == NULL)
        exit(1);

    // just a nicety for debugging ...
    // pretty print if stdin redirected from file
    struct termios tio;
    if (tcgetattr(fileno(stdin),&tio) < 0)
        fputs(buf,stdout);

    // strip the newline
    cp = strchr(buf,'\n');
    if (cp != NULL)
        *cp = 0;

    // lowercase the string
    for (;  *buf != 0;  ++buf)
        *buf = tolower((unsigned char) *buf);
}

int
main(void)
{

    char str1[MAX], str2[MAX];

    prompt(str1,sizeof(str1),"Enter string 1");
    prompt(str2,sizeof(str2),"Enter string 2");

    printf("\nOutput:\n");
    findSame(str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the actual program output:

```
Enter string 1: The quick Brown FOX jumped over the LAzy dog
Enter string 2: Hey Quick brown cat and dog

Output:
quick brown dog
```

Answer (score 2):

Code has problems including:

**Buffer overrun**

`"The quick Brown FOX jumped over the LAzy dog"` needs at least 46 bytes to store as a *string* and `str1[MAX]` is size 25.

- Drop using `gets()`.  It is not longer a part of the standard C library since 2011.
- Use `fgets()` and strip off the trailing `'\n'`.
- Use a wider buffer.
- Test if user attempted to enter much input.

```
// Candidate helper function
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Candidate helper function
char *read_line(const char *prompt, size_t sz, char dest[sz]) {
  if (prompt) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
  }
  if (fgets(dest, (int) sz, stdin) ==  NULL) {
    perror("No input");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  dest[strcspn(dest, "\n")] = '\0';  // Lop off potential trailing \n
  if (strlen(dest) + 1 >= sz) {
    perror("input too long");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return dest;
}
// To do: amend to flush input and re-prompt when input too long.


...
    // Sample usage

    //char str1[MAX], str2[MAX];
    //printf("Enter String 1: ");
    //gets(str1);
    //printf("Enter String 2: ");
    //gets(str2);

    #define LINE_MAX 100
    char str1[LINE_MAX + 1 + 1]; // 1 more for too long an input test, 1 more for \0
    read_line("Enter String 1: ", sizeof str1, str1);
    char str2[LINE_MAX + 1 + 1];
    read_line("Enter String 2: ", sizeof str2, str2);
```

**Fixing "word" compare loop**

Leave that for others (or later).

Comment: You might also mention the nested use of `strtok` which cannot work.

Comment: @chqrlie [Craig Estey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77435388/2410359) has `strtok()` trouble covered.

Comment: Not really: Craig shows that the nested tokenisation cannot work because splitting the second string cannot be done more than once, but he does not mention that nested splitting cannot work at all, not even once, because of the `strtok()` static state.

Answer (score 0):

There's been good feedback regarding not using `gets()` for input, and a too small buffer that overflows easily. The code below skirts those issues but using two "compile time" strings in order to get the desired logic happening. Accepting user input (with `fgets()`) is left for another day.

Below, each string is tokenised **separately**, forming two arrays of pointers to each token. Then, a trivial loop (not optimal) calls `stricmp()` that performs case insensitive comparison of tokens from both collections. When a match is found, it is reported to stdout`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **tokenise( char *str, const char *dlm, int *n ) {
    char *cp, *lw = str, **arr = NULL;
    for( int i = 0, stp = 2; stp--; i = 0 ) {
        for( cp = str; (cp = strtok(cp, dlm)) != NULL; cp = NULL, i++ )
            if( stp ) lw = cp; else arr[ i ] = cp;
        if( stp ) {
            while( lw > str ) if( !*--lw ) *lw = *dlm;
            arr = calloc( (*n = i) + 1, sizeof *arr );
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

int main( void ) {
    char *dlm = ",.! \t\n";

    char buf1[] = "dog,  CAT,  horse. APPLE!! Banana Grape cat  banana";
    puts( buf1 );
    int cnt1;
    char **arr1 = tokenise( buf1, dlm, &cnt1 );

    char buf2[] = "cat, banana, orange, grape, apple, box";
    puts( buf2 );
    int cnt2;
    char **arr2 = tokenise( buf2, dlm, &cnt2 );

    char *sep = "";
    for( int i = 0; i < cnt2; i++)
        for( int j = 0; j < cnt1; j++)
            if( stricmp( arr2[i], arr1[j] ) == 0 ) {
                printf( "%s%s", sep, arr1[j] );
                sep = ", ";
                break;
            }
    putchar( '\n' );

    free( arr2 );
    free( arr1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
dog,  CAT,  horse. APPLE!! Banana Grape cat  banana
cat, banana, orange, grape, apple, box
CAT, Banana, Grape, APPLE
```